# Multiple Selection Search Narrow

Tags: vba, search

I am wanting to create a catering search for my coworkers that allows them to pick things like people attending and food type and then it will narrow down the spreadsheet of catering options to those parameters. I am extremely new to VBA and been trying to search for how to do this but I feel like I don't know the correct terms. How would I go about making this happen if it even is possible?

what I want to be pulled

[image: what I want to be pulled]

Comment: What/where is the source of your data?

Comment: It is in an excell spreadsheet with the labels of Name, Food Type, Price Points, and people attending.